# How to pass a dynamic value from parent element to child element?

Tags: css, sass

I have a parent element that will calculate the 'left' value on xl screens like so:

```
&.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;

  @media only screen and (min-width: 758px) {
    left: calc(50% + 100px); // <----dynamically calculating left value, how to pass this value to child?

    .caption {
      left: calc(50% + 100px); // this value isn't the same as the parent value 
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out is how to get the parent's 'left' value (for example 250px) and set the child 'left' value as its inverse (-250px).

I tried:

1. setting child 'left' value to 'inherit'
2. calc((50% + 100px) * -1);

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to where you want the child to actually be positioned. Could you provide just enough HTML and any relevant additional CSS - especially is the child positioned relative to the parent? Make a runnable snippet - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Disregard the actual output/positioning :). Simply put, I want to take a calculated parent value and use its value in the child element

Comment: I suspect you'll need JS for a totally general answer.

Comment: You need to get the computed value from the parent, and there is no CSS way to do this.  You will need JS.  The inherit is working but it is inheriting the formula, not the evaluated result of the formula, from the parent. Hence for the parent the % is the % width of its parent and for the child the % is the % width of the parent.